# AgularJS Editable ui-grid input cell height issue in IE

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've ui-grid with 2 columns. Only 1st column is editable, when i try to edit it editableCellTemplate height doesn't fit with actual cell height(As shown in image). This bug only observed in IE, works fine with Chrome and Firefox. Is there any alternative to make it work.

[image]

editableCellTemplate is

```
<form class="ui-grid-cell-edit" name=\"inputForm\">
    <input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-class=\"\'colt\' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\">
</form>
```

Please check below link for example. Try to edit 'Description' column

http://jsfiddle.net/relly/p8d0qsas/

Update: IE version used

[image]

Comment: Which version of IE? Why are you escaping some of your quote characters? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't even included any of your CSS

Comment: As i'm using this template inside js file escape characters are added. I'm not using any custom css for this "ui-grid-cell-edit" is ui-grid inbuilt css.

Comment: Can You provide a working Fiddle please ?

Comment: @Ahsan Fiddle example added try to edit 'Description' column and observe cell height after double click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like its a grid CSS issue get applied to textbox when user double clicks on grid column.

But you can override this CSS,

```
div.ui-grid-cell input{
  padding:5px;
}
```

Here is updated sample, try to edit 'Description' and 'Price' column http://jsfiddle.net/0arkssqy/3/

Comment: Thank you for solution. If question is valid please up vote it.